# Notation for Capital $X$ not to be confused

Tags: math-mode

So  I am writing my thesis manuscript, and I should use the same notation  all over the manuscript. In my first two chapters I used `$X$` (capital x in math mode) as a notation for  random variables (as well as `$X_i$` for different random variables).

Now in my third chapter I should define an orthonormal  system (X,Y,Z). I am searching for a notation, so that it is not confused between `$X$` of the random variable and  X of the system.

I tried different math mode notations: `\mathbb{X}`, `\mathbf{X}`, `\mathcal{X}`, `\mathfrak{x}`, `\mathit{X}`, `$X$`, `\mathrm{X}`, `\mathsf{X}`, `\mathtt{X}`. However the letters seems quit same, so it can be easily confused.

The one that appears much distiguishable is `$\mathbb{X}$` however for Z it appears as `$\mathbb{Z}$`  which is usually used as the notation of the integer numbers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with LaTeX. Why don't you go with $x$ as most people do? `\mathbb` is reserved for something else, that's true. Before you try to mix many fonts, I would think about some other symbol for your variables. Let's say ´$\aleph´

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
$X$ versus $\mathscr{X}$
\end{document}
```

[image]